# Как подключить datagrip к microsoft sql server

Tags: sql, wpf, sql-server, datagrid

Хочу подключиться с помощью datagrip к microsoft sql server, в итоге получаю ошибку связанную с TCP. TCP/IP включил в менеджере SQL но права на вход с помощью учётки тоже дал. Возможно TCP/IP не правильно настроил. Так как говорят вроде 1433 порт надо где-то задать.

[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

По тексту ошибки можно сделать вывод, что вы забыли открыть порт `1433` для TCP/IP подключений.

Это возможно сделать в настройках SQL Server:
[image: sql server port configuration]

Более подробное описание настройки SQL Server и подключения к нему [описан в блоге DataGrip](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/06/21/connecting-datagrip-to-ms-sql-server/).